# In Eclipse, Is it possible to use support library when using the Android New Activity wizard

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

When using the the new activity wizard for an Android app in Eclipse

> File -> New -> Other -> Android -> Android Activity

I get the warning

> This template requires a minimum SDK version of at least 11, and the
>   current min version is 8

This happens for most of the options in the wizard but right now I want to create a new master detail activity which will make use of fragments.

I am using actionbar sherlock and I have the latest support library jar registered with the project. I would like to use the wizard as fragments are new to me and it seems like a lot of code is needed that I am unfamiliar with. So I'm using the wizards as both a learning process to understand how fragments should be implemented properly and fault free, which is something I'm not confident of doing manually just yet.

It seems to me totally obvious that I should be able to tell the wizard to make use of the support library methods and classes but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I could just change my min sdk level to 11, use the wizard, change the min sdk level back to 8 and make the support library changes that are needed but what a pain!

**Update**

How would I go about changing the source code of either Eclipse or the android sdk to achieve this as both are open source right? Where should I start looking?
Any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: Great question, I've wondered this myself. I usually just put it at 11 temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

*The New Android Application* wizard does not allow you to select / add third party support libraries to your project while creating a new project. The only library it will add by default is the `android-support-v4.jar` library.

It is a small trade-off I suppose. The new wizard, especially the *Android Activity*, does simplify things when creating new Activities quickly. But I suppose, it is something we will have to live with until Google adds such a provision. That is, if they choose to add it sometime down the line.

**Update 1**

Eclipse is Open Source. These are all the sources available for the Eclipse Source: http://git.eclipse.org/c/. However, I don't think modifying Eclipse would be helpful. I am almost certain, it is more ADT's / SDK's doing than Eclipse per-se. But I am merely speculating on this one.

**Update 2**

You can download the SDK source from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/. Good luck. :-)

Comment: thanks for your response. Eclipse is open source right? So how would I go about changing the source to do this? Where would I start?